# Sorry for not been/being able to participate?

Tags: grammar

Is

> *Sorry for not **been** able to participate*

in the meeting despite being very vocal about his subject on the group (the meeting already happened)

or

> *Sorry for not **being** able to participate* [...]

correct?

Comment: The first one would not be used by a native speaker.

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry for not being able to participate

is grammatically correct. One should use only noun after a preposition. Therefore, gerund (verb + ing) is the right choice. However, if you want to use 'been', in this case, the following sentence works, too:

> Sorry for not having been able to participate...

Comment: Can 'Sorry for not being able to participate' be used even when meeting is over?

Comment: Yes. If you were apologising in advance you would say something like "I'm sorry, I will not be able to attend the meeting".